# Why doesn't metapost know about the path in my feynmp code?

Tags: metapost, feynmf

I'm trying to use FeynMP to draw a Feynman diagram exactly like this

[image: Feynman diagram for Hartree contribution to fermion self-energy]

but with a photon line inside the circle. This code works perfectly to create the diagram above:

```
\fmfleft{i} \fmfright{o} \fmftop{t}
\fmf{fermion,label=$q$}{i,v1,o}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{photon,label=$0$}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion,right,tension=0.45,label=$k$}{v2,t}
\fmf{fermion,right,tension=0.45}{t,v2}
```

but when I try to add

```
\fmfposition
\fmfipath{p[]}
\fmfiset{p1}{vpath1(__v2,__t)}
\fmfiset{p2}{vpath2(__t,__v2)}
\fmfi{photon}{point 3length(p1)/4 of p1 -- point 3length(p2)/4 of p2}
```

to create the photon line, MetaPost gives me the error

```
unknown path p1
```

On the other hand, this code, adapted from the FeynMF manual,

```
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmf{dots}{i,v1}
\fmf{dots}{v2,o}
\fmf{phantom,left,tension=0.2,tag=1}{v1,v2}
\fmf{phantom,left,tension=0.2,tag=2}{v2,v1}
\fmfdot{v1,v2}
\fmfposition
\fmfipath{p[]}
\fmfiset{p1}{vpath1(__v1,__v2)}
\fmfiset{p2}{vpath2(__v2,__v1)}
\fmfi{fermion}{subpath (0,length(p1)/3) of p1}
\fmfi{fermion}{subpath (2length(p1)/3,length(p1)) of p1}
\fmfi{fermion}{subpath (0,length(p2)/3) of p2}
\fmfi{fermion}{subpath (2length(p2)/3,length(p2)) of p2}
\fmfi{gluon}{point length(p1)/10 of p1
-- point 11length(p1)/12 of p1}
```

successfully creates this diagram:

[image: working example of fmfi]

What's the difference, and how do I fix it?

Edit: As requested, the complete (non-working) code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%Feynman diagrams
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{fmffile}{Calculation2Diagrams}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(200,150)

   % This code works fine...
   \fmfleft{i} \fmfright{o} \fmftop{t}
   \fmf{fermion,label=$q$}{i,v1,o}
   \fmffreeze
   \fmf{photon,label=$0$}{v1,v2}
   \fmf{fermion,right,tension=0.45,label=$k$}{v2,t}
   \fmf{fermion,right,tension=0.45}{t,v2}
   % ...just as long as this code isn't added to it.
   \fmfposition
   \fmfipath{p[]}
   \fmfiset{p1}{vpath1(__v2,__t)}
   \fmfiset{p2}{vpath2(__t,__v2)}
   \fmfi{photon}{point 3length(p1)/4 of p1 -- point 3length(p2)/4 of p2}

   % This code, adapted from the FeynMF manual, on the other hand, does
   % almost the same thing in almost the same way and works perfectly.
   %\fmfleft{i}
   %\fmfright{o}
   %\fmf{plain}{i,v1}
   %\fmf{plain}{v2,o}
   %\fmf{phantom,left,tension=0.2,tag=1}{v1,v2}
   %\fmf{phantom,left,tension=0.2,tag=2}{v2,v1}
   %\fmfdot{v1,v2}
   %\fmfposition
   %\fmfipath{p[]}
   %\fmfiset{p1}{vpath1(__v1,__v2)}
   %\fmfiset{p2}{vpath2(__v2,__v1)}
   %\fmfi{plain}{subpath (0,length(p1)/3) of p1}
   %\fmfi{plain}{subpath (2length(p1)/3,length(p1)) of p1}
   %\fmfi{plain}{subpath (0,length(p2)/3) of p2}
   %\fmfi{plain}{subpath (2length(p2)/3,length(p2)) of p2}
   %\fmfi{plain}{point length(p1)/10 of p1
   %-- point 9length(p1)/10 of p1}

  \end{fmfgraph*}
 \end{fmffile}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you leave out the suffixes from the `vpath` macros.

```
\fmfiset{p1}{vpath(__v2,__t)}
\fmfiset{p2}{vpath(__t,__v2)}
```

What the suffixes are supposed to be doing is a mystery to me.

Here's a complete program using `feynmp-auto`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{first}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(200,200)
    \fmfleft{i} \fmfright{o} \fmftop{t}
\fmf{fermion,label=$q$}{i,v1,o}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{photon,label=$0$}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion,right,tension=0.45,label=$k$}{v2,t}
\fmf{fermion,right,tension=0.45}{t,v2}
\fmfposition
\fmfipath{p[]}
\fmfiset{p1}{vpath(__v2,__t)}
\fmfiset{p2}{vpath(__t,__v2)}
\fmfi{photon}{point 3/4 length p1 of p1 -- point 3/4 length p2 of p2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda wondering that. If anybody does know what the suffixes do, please chime in.

Comment: @Thruston Is there a possibility to draw a line from one Point on the circle to an extern point? For instance `\fmfi{photon}{point 3/4 length p1 of p1 -- o}` or something like that?

Comment: @Matthias, yes you could do that - why don't you experiment with it and see what you get?  If you get stuck, then ask a new question - that way we can keep questions and answers inline with each other.